# need source code of libraries to run on android

Tags: java, android, amazon-ec2

I need the sourcecode for these libraries:

- commons-codec-1.3
- commons-httpclient-3.0.1
- commons-logging-1.1
- log4j-1.2.14
- jaxb-ri-2.1

I need the code to recompile it in eclipse in android app and use it with javax.xml packages as you know javax.xml can not be used in eclipse in an android project.
All of this is to use the Amazon-EC2 SDK to access them from android mobile.

Comment: Try the project pages and dont forget to read the license! double post already closed -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982666/need-sorce-code-of-libraries-closed

Answer (score 0):

> all of thes is to use amazon-ec2 sdk to access them from android mobile

Your list of JARs is incorrect. The [current AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) does not use log4j or jaxb, but does use other libraries.

You may better served finding another way to access the Amazon AWS API that requires fewer third-party dependencies, such as [typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/), or simply invoking the [query API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2010-08-31/DeveloperGuide/) directly using HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

> All of this is to use the Amazon-EC2 SDK to access them from android mobile.

AWS now provides a dedicated [AWS SDK for Android developers](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/). I would take a look at this as it may provide the functionality you need without you having to satisfy a lot of other dependencies.