# aws support on android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

Simple question - if I am developing and Android application that wants to access Amazon cloud (AWS services) - can you suggest me options?
More detailed for what I have done till now: I am trying to include existing AWS libraries for Java - but Dalvik does not support them all - finally the issue I am still not able to resolve is with AWS SDK third-party library stax-api-1.0.1.jar as it cannot be recompiled for Dalvik as others (Android complains I try to recompile a core-library)...

Please give any suggestions on those issues,
Best,
Sanja

Answer (score 4):

[As I wrote previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982843/need-sorce-code-of-libraries-to-run-on-android), you may better served finding another way to access the Amazon AWS API that requires fewer third-party dependencies, such as [typica](http://code.google.com/p/typica/), or simply invoking the [query API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2010-08-31/DeveloperGuide/) directly using HttpClient.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. But I am not sure wheter it solves the issue - I am aware of typica and jets3, but they are again dependent on those libraries I cannot compile to Android (particularly stax-api.jar as Dalvik complains I try to recompile core-library)... I posted this question on few more forums.

Comment: Maybe query API will be a solution - but it seems I will need to implement my own request signing and so - which seems a bit complex so I was trying to avoid...

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [AWS SDK for Android](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/)? It's in beta and doesn't yet support all services, but it's a solid start.

Comment: Hi,I have seen, but now I have to devote to some other things, hopefully I will try it out later.Thanks for the info.

Comment: Now out of beta and with samples showing how to implement common mobile features, like photo uploads to S3: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread; However, AWS now supports a new SDK named AWS SDK for Kotlin that lets you develop Android apps that can invoke AWS services. Here is a end to end example of creating an Android App using the Kotlin SDK that can invoke AWS Services such as Amazon DynamoDB.

[Creating your first Native Android application using the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/.kotlin_alpha/usecases/first_android_app)