# use amazon aws-java-sdk-1.0.11 in android

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i need a way to use aws-java-sdk-1.0.11 in android as when i try to import the jar files of third-party it give me an error delvik conversion error i want to use only ec2

Comment: possible duplicate of [aws support on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997636/aws-support-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the [Android SDK for AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) to see if it has the functionality you need without having as many problematic dependencies.